# datepicker widget hide on month/year select

Tags: jquery

```
$('.custom_datepicker_selector').datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
}).on('changeDate', function(en) {

  alert("HI");
});
```

Currently I'm using bootstrap-datepicker.js.

Datepicker widget is automatically hide on month and year select even after I set my datepicker options as

```
datePickerOptions.changeMonth = true;
datePickerOptions.changeYear = true;
```

I want to hide datepicker only on date select not on month and year select. How to do that ?

Comment: I won't downvote you as someoneelse, but yes, it's true. Where is the question, where is the problem... ??? We are not physically with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case 'span':
                    if (!target.is('.disabled')) {
                        this.viewDate.setUTCDate(1);
                        if (target.is('.month')) {
                            var day = 1;
                            var month = target.parent().find('span').index(target);
                            var year = this.viewDate.getUTCFullYear();
                            this.viewDate.setUTCMonth(month);
                            this._trigger('changeMonth', this.viewDate);
                            if (this.o.minViewMode === 1) {
                                this._setDate(UTCDate(year, month, day,0,0,0,0));
                            }
                        } else {
                            var year = parseInt(target.text(), 10)||0;
                            var day = 1;
                            var month = 0;
                            this.viewDate.setUTCFullYear(year);
                            this._trigger('changeYear', this.viewDate);
                            if (this.o.minViewMode === 2) {
                                this._setDate(UTCDate(year, month, day,0,0,0,0));
                            }
                        }
                        this.showMode(-1);
                        this.fill(); // when execute this function, datepicker widget is hide;
```

If we comment **this.fill()** or if we call this **this.fill()** based on the changeYear, changeMonth condition, then it works as we expected.